# Nautilus slow on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: nautilus

Since I installed ubuntu 12.10 I noticed that nautilus is a bit slow. Especially when switching between windows loading is not instantaneous but I have to wait about 2 seconds to change the window.

What might be the problem? How can I fix?

Comment: Please tell us what applications are on your desktop.

Comment: I use the latest version of gnome-shell and very few applications. I run the 32-bit version of Ubuntu 12.10. 
What can I say to You to help me to solve my problem?

Comment: It's been a long time I said goodbye to Gnome and have been using Xubuntu. You can just try installing thunar and see if it works better, for you, than Nautilus.

Comment: I suggest, you disable your shell-extensions, one by one over a longer period of time and use (after rebooting the system), to make sure, that there isn't any problem there.